# Telrik JustMock integration with VSTS build hosted agent

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, telerik, azure-pipelines, justmock

I am using Telrik JustMock to mock in the unit testing. Locally it works well but while I try to integrate it with VSTS builds based on Asp.net build template, it ends with errors.
The stacktrace for the errors are as following:

```
 Failed   ValidateNodeRegisteredReturnsTrue
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0452600Z Error Message:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0452600Z    Assert.IsFalse failed. 
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0452600Z Stack Trace:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0452600Z    at 

 xxx.UnitTests.TemplateManagerUnitTests.ValidateNodeRegisteredReturnsTrue() in d:\a\1\s\Dev\TSys Project\8. Unit
```

Tests\XXX.WebMVC.Tests\UnitTests\ManagerUnitTests.cs:line 36

```
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z 
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Failed   ValidateExtractPackageOnLocalServer
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Error Message:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    Test method 
 xxx.UnitTests.ManagerUnitTests.ValidateExtractPackageOnLocalServer threw exception: 

2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Telerik.JustMock.Core.ElevatedMockingException: Cannot mock 'TemplateCreationService.TemplateUtility'. The profiler must be enabled to mock, arrange or execute the specified target.
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Detected active third-party profilers:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z * Visual Studio 2015 Code Coverage/IntelliTrace (from process environment)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Disable the profilers or link them from the JustMock configuration utility. Restart the test runner and, if necessary, Visual Studio after linking.
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Stack Trace:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z     at Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.ThrowElevatedMockingException(MemberInfo member)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.InterceptStatics(Type type, IEnumerable`1 mixins, IEnumerable`1 supplementaryBehaviors, IEnumerable`1 fallbackBehaviors, Boolean mockStaticConstructor)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.MockBuilder.InterceptStatics(MocksRepository repository, Type type, Nullable`1 behavior, Boolean mockStaticConstructor)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<SetupStatic>b__0()
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.GuardInternal(Action guardedAction)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Mock.SetupStatic(Type staticType)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at xxx.UnitTests.ManagerUnitTests.ValidateExtractPackageOnLocalServer() in d:\a\1\s\Dev\TSys Project\8. Unit Tests\xxx.WebMVC.Tests\ServiceUnitTests\ManagerUnitTests.cs:line 44

2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z 
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Error Message:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    Test method 
xxx.UnitTests.ManagerUnitTests.ShouldAssertCustomValueForDateTimeNow threw exception: 
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Telerik.JustMock.Core.ElevatedMockingException: Cannot mock 'System.DateTime'. The profiler must be enabled to mock, arrange or execute the specified target.
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Detected active third-party profilers:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z * Visual Studio 2015 Code Coverage/IntelliTrace (from process environment)
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Disable the profilers or link them from the JustMock configuration utility. Restart the test runner and, if necessary, Visual Studio after linking.
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z Stack Trace:
2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z     at
```

Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.ThrowElevatedMockingException(MemberInfo member)
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.InterceptStatics(Type type, IEnumerable`1 mixins, IEnumerable`1 supplementaryBehaviors, IEnumerable`1 fallbackBehaviors, Boolean mockStaticConstructor)
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.MockBuilder.InterceptStatics(MocksRepository repository, Type type, Nullable`1 behavior, Boolean mockStaticConstructor)
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.ConvertExpressionToCallPattern(Expression expr, CallPattern callPattern)
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Core.MocksRepository.Arrange[TMethodMock](Expression expr, Func`1 methodMockFactory)
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1.b__0()
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Core.ProfilerInterceptor.GuardInternal[T](Func`1 guardedAction)
     2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at Telerik.JustMock.Mock.Arrange[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
    2017-08-04T08:24:12.0462606Z    at

```
 xxx.UnitTests.ManagerUnitTests.ShouldAssertCustomValueForDateTimeNow() in d:\a\1\s\Dev\TSys Project\8. Unit Tests\xxx.WebMVC.Tests\ServiceUnitTests\ManagerUnitTests.cs:line 57

 2017-08-04T08:24:12.0472600Z Failed   ShouldAssertCustomValueForDateTimeNow
```

Can anyone share if have the knowledge for Telrik JustMock integration with VSTS asp.net build template.

I was able to findout the link for running Telrik JustMock using XAML based build template here:
http://docs.telerik.com/help/justmock/integration-tfs-2013.html

Also I am using Test Run task of Asp.Net build template.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Handling the ["Profiler must be enabled" exception in JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/justmock/details/handling-the-profiler-must-be-enabled-exception-in-justmock) article, the free version is not allowed to use the profiler. Also, a thread of [NuGet package for JustMock pr](http://www.telerik.com/forums/nuget-package-for-justmock-pro)o.

You need to [setup a on-premise build agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) on your server that have JustMock installed and this private build agent is running under your account.

Comment: thanks for the reply and this fact was well known. Telrik guys told me that some of their clients were able to run the profile with hosted build agents somehow and we should give a try for it. So we are trying for that.

Comment: @Riky But base on [Hosted agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted) article, there isn't JustMock.

Comment: for your knowledge, it is not always required that you can only do something using the tools which are available with hosted agents. You can pass them as dependencies in an elevated fashion. for example, nunit is not available but you can pass a reference of NUint as test dependency in the test assembly task. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Riky The issue is that there isn't any way to enable Profiler on Hosted Agent since you cannot install any software on the hosted agent. Even you provide required dependency and files, you don't have administrator permission to register the DLLs for profiler.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT, although we do not need to install profiler on Hosted agent it can work on a elevated mode. But somehow it require to set a machine level environment variable and we do not have permission to set this so yes there is a problem on hosted agents. But this is weird behavior from the JustMock profiler.. Ideally I can set the process level environment variables and JustMock should work using those variables. Telrik team should make a provision for that.

Comment: @Riky What're environment variables?